# How to include tests when creating a Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, testing, dockerfile

I created a [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/rutgerhofste/gisdocker/) a couple of months ago that creates a linux image with a couple of anaconda python virtual environments with different packages.

Due to some reason, one of the modules in python35 cannot be imported anymore (GDAL) which raised a bigger question: How to include tests when writing dockerfiles?

I want to test if the modules work as expected for the different python environments. Some modules do not throw errors during installation but have some broken dependencies, hence the testing.

A first import test would already be helpful:

in python27

```
import module1 
import module2
..
import moduleN
```

in python35

```
import module1  
import module2 
..
import moduleN
```

The workflow would be as follows:
Compile image -> Run tests -> Dissemination using docker hub

How to include the testing step in this workflow?

[EDIT] I included two lines in my dockerfile:

```
COPY test_python27.py /
RUN [ "/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/bin/python", "./test_python27.py" ]
```

that will run a python script. However the output of that script is not captured by the docker log. More importantly Errors such as the ZeroDivisionError do not cause the build to fail. How to solve this?

Comment: I wrote some shell to perform search and replace of strings in my Dockerfile so each environment has a synthesized custom Dockerfile

Comment: if your Dockerfile build exits some command with something else that 0, it stops the build, so if you add this to Dockerfile it will always cancel build `RUN exit 420`

Comment: Could I just `RUN python27test.py` and store the python27test.py file in the same directory as the dockerfile?

Comment: you have to copy it first to the image with `COPY` and it might work

Comment: I am now trying :`ADD test_python27.py /`
`CMD [ "/opt/anaconda3/envs/python27/bin/python", "./test_python27.py" ]`

Comment: CMD is when you start container, you have to add it to `RUN`